# Notification not show any button

Tags: notifications

how to fix notification not show button?
When i receive file via bluetooth, notification is show but don't have any button for accept or cancel.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

i can not accept. If i click it, do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

These are just notifications, letting you know that something happened, not dialogues expecting your actions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you cannot do anything with or about it from that notification. If you want to do anything regarding the notification, you must go to the option it is referring to, in your case, it is the bluetooth option. This  might seem weird for an ex-windows user that is used to getting an action upon clicking the notification but this is how eOS works.

Comment: if i use ubuntu desktop and open bluetooth settings, i can receive files from my phone. But if i use pantheon desktop and open bluetooth settings, i can not. So, this is the bug in pantheon desktop (maybe bluetooth settings is bug)

Comment: Yes, you cannot do that. I just checked. You should try using some application for sharing files instead. Check out this list for the same: https://alternativeto.net/software/shareit/?platform=linux